# recieve data form html in angular undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker

Well I have a simple form for add data, but I have the problem with the date when I enter to from added or choose the date but the date always result undefined, BUT I reload the page and work, Honestly this is the strangest thing for me. for choose date I use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="../../../assets/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../assets/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">
        Fecha Control:
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="date_food" name="date_food" ng-model="date_food">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#date_food').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                language: "es",
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

button for add

```
<button ng-click="addExtraDining()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Agregar comida extra
</button>
```

and the function

```
$scope.addExtraDining = function () {
            console.log(document.getElementsByName("date_food").value); //undefined
            console.log($scope.date_food); //undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**getElementsByName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) gives a nodelist collection. Therefore you need to  pass the index to get the element like this

```
document.getElementsByName("date_food")[0].value
```

Since `date_food` is the id of the dom element , you can use `document.getElementById('date_food')`

You can note the difference between two text `getElementsByName` & `getElementById`. In once case it is *elements* where in othercase it is *element*